# Find hidden dependencies in Ivy

Tags: java, log4j, ivy, dependency-management

I'm using Apache Ivy + IvyDE for getting my project's dependencies, which are:

```
    <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="r08" />

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.6.1" />
    <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="0.9.27" />

    <!-- database -->
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-entitymanager" rev="3.6.2.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="4.1.0.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-c3p0" rev="3.6.2.Final" />
    <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.14" />
```

Sources are the Maven and JBoss (Hibernate) repositories.

As you can see I'm using logback+SLF4J for logging, but for some reason Ivy will download log4j and slf4j-log4j as well, which causes a few small problem in my application.

Is there a way to see why this happens, to see which of the dependencies above depend on log4j? Can I get a dependency graph/tree generated from Ivy/IvyDE?

And is there then a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have an ant target that looks like this:

```
<target name="report" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="report" />
    <!-- 
     The type attribute is optional, we're using it to exlude other dependcy types we're not interested in. 
     Note that each resolve uses that list (via a property) in our build. 
    -->
    <ivy:resolve type="jar,ejb,tld,bundle"/> 
    <ivy:report todir="report" />
</target>
```

Then it's just a call `ant report` and Ivy will generate the report as HTML in the given directory.

Take a look at [the Ivy documentation for ivy:report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html).

Edit:

To prevent the inclusion of those artifacts/dependencies, you could try `transitive="false"` on the `<dependency ..>` element, or use `<exclude>`. For example, we use Hibernate 3 but don't want to have `JTA 1.1`, so our `ivy.xml` containts this: `<exclude module="jta"/>` to exclude all transitive JTA dependencies.

Comment: Works perfectly, report to find the culprit (hibernate-validator), exclude to cut log4j out

Comment: No wait, I still get log4j when building with Ant, or running from Eclipse, even though it doesn't show up in the ivy.xml [*] listing in Eclipse.

Comment: Well, there might be another dependency that has log4j as a transitive dep. Did you globally exclude log4j, not just for hibernate-validator?

Comment: I didn't exclude it globally, but according to the report only hibernate-validator depends on it.

Comment: Never mind, it was because log4j was in an included Eclipse project

Comment: Where does this code snippet go? I tried putting it in build.xml and got errors regarding the ivy prefix in ivy:resolve.

Comment: @AnnKilzer yes, this snippet has to be added to build.xml. Of course you'd also have to add the ivy plugin/taskdefs as well.

Comment: @AlekseiEgorov it's a property that contains a comma separated list of types, e.g. `jar,ejb,tld,bundle`. I'll adapt the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to build on Thomas' answer and recommend adding a "conf" declaration to the dependencies:

```
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.6.1" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="0.9.27" conf="default"/>
```

This will reduce the transitive dependencies to the default sub-set, which in Maven terminology is the jars on the "compile" scope.

Without this setting you get all the dependencies which includes lot of optional stuff you won't need.

Comment: @mark : I tried following but its not working :
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17" conf="default"/>
any help?

Comment: @tejas you need to supply more details about what's going wrong. My first guess is perhaps you are behind a network proxy? I suggest post a new question.

Comment: @tejas Ahhh, then I'm guessing you've created your own configurations and "default" is not present. Cannot confirm without more information.

Comment: Oh ! now I get it. Yes you are right I did create compile,runtime,runtime-test configurations. I didn't know default comes from there. I was assuming its something that is supported irrespective. Thanks for help.