# com.ibm.websphere#uow;6.0.2.17: not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ivy

I am new to Ivy and am a chronic ant user, so repositories are still sort of new to me.

I have a Spring 4 project and I'm attempting to build my data access stuff using Hibernate. I have the following ivy.mxl file being imported into my build.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="apache" module="data"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.eclipse.persistence" name="org.eclipse.persistence.core" rev="2.5.2-M1" />
        <dependency org="org.eclipse.persistence" name="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa" rev="2.5.2-M1" />
        <dependency org="com.ibm.websphere" name="com.springsource.com.ibm.websphere.uow" rev="6.0.2.17" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="4.0.3.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="4.0.3.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-orm" rev="4.0.3.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-tx" rev="4.0.3.RELEASE" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I added the uow line as a result of this problem. When I build, I get the following message:

```
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.ibm.websphere#uow;6.0.2.17: not found
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I google for this error and found nothing.

I found the library here: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.com.ibm.websphere.uow&version=6.0.2.17 and added the following to my ivysettings.xml file as a result of the FAQ from this link:

```
    <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
        <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
    </url>
    <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
        <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
    </url>
```

And then added to my chain:

```
        <resolver ref="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release"/>
        <resolver ref="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external"/>
```

None of this has made any impact to my error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I found here: [Find hidden dependencies in Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405310/find-hidden-dependencies-in-ivy) I added transitive="false" to my dependency and it quit bringing it in.

Answer (score 0):

Using this dependency statement I was able to resolve the problem.

```
 <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-tx" rev="3.2.9.RELEASE"  
 transitive="false" conf="compile->default;runtime->default;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is located in the Redhat GA repo.

I added the repo to the resolvers in ivysettings.xml.

```
<resolvers>
    <chain name="chained" returnFirst="true">
        <ibiblio name="redhat" root="https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
</resolvers>
```

I use the search facilities at http://mvnrepository.com/ . This lists where a library/artefact can be found.